# How do I maximize compatibility for a video-playing webapp deployed on USB drives?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, internet-explorer-7, jwplayer

I'm currently using HTML/Javascript based web app with JWPlayer 6 that has a chapter selection menu and plays the corresponding video. The web app will be deployed on USB drives and delivered to a variety of clients, so I went the HTML5 route for best compatibility and the least hassle...but later on I discovered many of the clients may be using IE7 and similar-era browsers.

I've ran into problems due to Adobe Flash's security protocols that limit the app from accessing the local SWF and video files from the USB drive. That is, the user will have to give Flash permission to access the files from the USB drive — an unrealistic demand for the clients (many are trained on a computer only for specific uses).

Is there a way to circumvent Flash's security protocols to ensure IE7+ compatibility from the flash drive? Or will I have to go another route for delivering the video for outdated hardware?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog](http://blog.beverlyguillermo.com/post/14813549122/ie7-and-html5-video). Someone else found a solution using [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/), [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), and [HTML5Shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Comment: JW6 wont' work offline, but JW5 will.